# Accessing Hadoop from PHP

Tags: php, hadoop, thrift, hdfs

I need to access from PHP the HDFS on a Hadoop system which uses **cloudera packages** in **version 0.20.2+923.256**.

There is a thrift server for the namenode which runs and also
one for the job tracker. I have the following function for accessing the hdfs, but
I get an unknown method "**listStatus**" error. The thrift server is used also by HUE interface to access the HDFS and the job tracker.

Can you help me please to access that HDFS from PHP? Does that thrift uses another API?
I didn't find any specification for that API.

```
$socket = new TSocket(IP,PORT);
$socket->setSendTimeout(10000);
$socket->setRecvTimeout(20000);
$transport = new TBufferedTransport($socket);
$protocol = new TBinaryProtocol($transport);

$client = new ThriftHadoopFileSystemClient($protocol);
$transport->open();
$pathname = new Pathname(array('pathname' => $file));
$result = $client->listStatus($pathname);
echo($result[0]->path);        
$transport->close();
return $result;
```

Many thanks!

Comment: did you got any solution for this question?

Answer (score 1):

you can you this api, its helpful 
https://github.com/simpleenergy/php-WebHDFS